# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException compose jetpack

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to apply dynamic gradient to surface.  When new image is shown, based on the color of this image the gradient will change. Like in google samples,

```
@Composable
fun DatingHomeScreen() {

var imageId = remember { mutableStateOf(R.drawable.camelia) }
val defaultBitmap = imageResource(id = imageId.value).asAndroidBitmap()
var currentBitmap = mutableStateOf(defaultBitmap)
val swatch = generateDominantColorState(currentBitmap.value)
val dominantColors = listOf(Color(swatch.rgb), Color.Black)

 Box(
        modifier = boxModifier.verticalGradientBackground(
            dominantColors
        )
    ){
    IconButton(
       onClick = {
           imageId.value = getRandomImageId()
             }
          )
   }

}
```

but after third image app crashes with:

```
   java.util.concurrentmodificationexception
```

Comment: Can you post your entire stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

`getRandomImageId()` is probably performing an asynchronous task and updating the value of the image. If the flow to update the image is not contained to one instance at a time, the exception would occur.

Take a look at https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException